# loading data from service and update listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a web service and am loading data from that to a listview. I write to get 25 items from the Service after the user scrolls the listview to the end to get another 20 items from the Service and add to the listview, please help me to do this.

Comment: Have u done code for get all items from webservice? Please Post

Comment: yes. now how to refresh listview?

Comment: call `notifyDataSetChanged()` of `adapter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using webservice [PHP,.net] you can manage call for calling bunch of data [In your case its 25] ,You can call for 25 records at a time rather to call all the data from the server , and when user scrolls down you can call again webservice to get rest of 25 data and so on

Comment: now my question is, how to merge data to list view?

Comment: You do not need to merge the data, you can just add data in your preloaded datatype [Arraylist...etc]

Comment: No, as I am not having sample demo right now, But you can do just by sending 25 element in array in to your webservice, and after 25 just manage flage so that you can start from 26 to 50 and so on

Answer (score 0):

#### Create OnScrollListener:

```
list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


        }

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if(firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount == totalItemCount && totalItemCount!=0)
            {
                if(flag_loading == false)
                {
                    flag_loading = true;
                    additems();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```